# print(list(1,2,3)) is long and ugly; how to print lists using print [ie, pretty-printing without having to switch between print vs paste0]

Tags: r, pretty-print

I often get tired of writing this idiom for my console pretty-printing:

```
writeLines(paste0(“a=“, someObj))
```

and so I do this:

```
wp = function(obj) {
    writeLines(paste0(obj))
}
```

The reason I use `paste0` above is because it collapses `list`‘s nicely:

`print(list(1,2))` :

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[2] 2     # ah... my eyes >.<
```

vs `paste0(list(1,2),collapse=‘,’)`:

```
[1]  “1,2,3”    # ahhh much better
```

•  However, the `wp` function doesn’t print an obj of type matrix nicely due to `paste0`:

`m = matrix(list(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,byrow=T)`
`paste0(m)`

```
[1] “1” “3” “2” “4”    # yikes, this is supposed to be a matrix... my eyes
```

This quickly looks super ugly if

`m=matrix(list(list(1,2),list(3,4),list(5,6),list(7,8)),nrow=2,byrow=T)`
`paste0(m)`

```
[1] “list(1, 2)” “list(5, 6)” “list(3, 4)” “list(7, 8)”   # yikes again
```

whereas now, conversely, `print` does the better job for compact-printing of matrices:

`m=matrix(list(list(1,2),list(3,4),list(5,6),list(7,8)),nrow=2,byrow=T)`
`print(m)`

```
      [,1]    [,2]
[1,]  List,2  List,2
[2,]  List,2  List,2   # ah.. much better...
```

•  So my question is, how to make a better `wp` pretty-printer without inserting obscene dynamic type checks everywhere:

```
wp = function(obj) {
   if (typeof(obj) == ‘matrix’)
      writeLines(print(obj))
   else if (typeof(obj) == ‘list’)
      writeLines(paste0(obj,collapse=‘,’))
   else 
      # etc ...
}
```

There must be a better way to do this in base-R.  I prefer having my own compact utils instead of including a bunch of packages, but feel free to offer package solutions if it really does boil down to doing dynamic type checks.

Comment: So you want a function that prints in the way that you prefer, but the way that you prefer is different depending on which class you are printing, yet you don't want the function to have to check the class? Or am I misunderstanding you? Every type of object in R that you `print` uses a specific `print` method, and there are lots of them. A function like you describe would be possible, but incredibly complex if it were to be comprehensive. It would be better to write an S3 generic with one method for each  class you would prefer to print differently, and which defaults to `print`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for attempting to understand my question. Yes.. you stated what I was asking precisely. s3 is ok for custom classes, but using your s3 solution for built-in matrix() types.. wouldn’t I have to unclass a matrix and re-class it just to pretty-print properly? I think that may end up causing more hassle than I set out to fix.. ideally the solution to my problem is if R language designer changed the default implementation of print(list) to print a collapsed version and then do the super-verbose print on toggle by user.

Comment: Also, I’m not too worried about getting print to work with my own s3 types. I just wanted a good solution for most built-in types.

Comment: ok, yeah, I ended up just doing some of my own printUtils that hide more complexity under the hood.  I was hoping someone would have known some hidden feature in base-R that, for example, toggles the print(list()) to print sanely and compactly... not the super-verbose version (overkill).  But I don’t think such a solution exists. Thanks anyways. I did attempt to google for this but found nothing.  It may be good to leave it up for future code-ocd types like me to stumble across >.<

Comment: I guess the R authors already think they have a good solution for different types (balancing the needs of different users). I agree that default list printing seems to take up too much vertical space (though there's always `str` for a more concise version). I don't think there is any way to do this without type checking. If you want different methods for different classes, then well, you need different methods for different classes...

Comment: @AllanCameron Yup! Agreed, thanks. I will just hide the type checks or just manually have different types of print defaults for the primitive types. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the print methods - even the ones for built-in types.

```
print.list <- function(x, ...) {
  writeLines(paste0(x, collapse = ","))
}

print(list(1, 2))
#> 1,2
```

Or, you can create your own function.

```
wp <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("wp")
}

wp.default <- print

wp.list <- function(x, ...) {
  writeLines(paste0(x, collapse = ","))
}

wp(list(1, 2))
#> 1,2

wp(matrix(1:6, nrow = 2))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    3    5
#> [2,]    2    4    6
```

Comment: Wow, that’s really cool. I didn’t know we could monkey-patch R; but this is a great solution. I had naturally just assumed there was some pointer modification restrictions to those built-ins (haha..).   Thanks for letting us know.  Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I too am struggling to learn the base library of R.  format() is my new-found friend!  I don't yet know why matrix() isn't format-friendly... but trusty old data.frame can come to the rescue with a not-terribly-ugly workaround...

```
> format(list(1,2))
[1] "1" "2"
> m <- matrix(list(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,byrow=T)
> format.data.frame(as.data.frame.matrix(m))
  V1 V2
1  1  2
2  3  4
> m <- matrix(list(list(1,2),list(3,4),list(5,6),list(7,8)),nrow=2,byrow=T)
> format.data.frame(as.data.frame.matrix(m))
    V1   V2
1 1, 2 3, 4
2 5, 6 7, 8
>
```

By the way, I have rewritten your examples because I have formed the impression that using "=" for an assignment is very hazardous -- because it's heavily overloaded, and the semantics of R have some very surprising corner-cases (at least for a novice such as myself).  I think you'll avoid tripping over some nasty semantic surprises, if you use the "=" operator only for binding the formal name of a parameter to the actual parameter in a function call, or in the (rare) cases you really do want to use a second name for the same object (despite the semantic confusion this will cause if the underlying object is modified).